# Does it make sense to convert a react-native app to a PWA?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, progressive-web-apps

Right now, the way I see it is you choose either writing a PWA or a React-Native app depending on how much you want to optimize for web vs mobile. Does it make sense to think about writing a PWA with React Native, or perhaps converting an existing React Native app to a PWA?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask, an On Topic question, then look at the Question Checklist, the perfect question, how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example and take the tour

Answer (score 0):

I would consider maybe just implementing some of the things you can from PWA spec if you can. I wouldn't make PWA replace the Native app but if you are thinking of making a web app you can definitely make it PWA. They can be companions.

To meet PWA standards there are requirements you have to meet. Some of those things can have benefits regardless of the reasons for implementation.

- Service Workers can have a lot of perf benefits for instance and a good offline experience.
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps